# Eclipse mars error de puerto en páginas web

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Estoy usando eclipse mars, tomcat v8.5 y jre.1.8.0.9

Al momento de querer hacer mi primera prueba me sale esto y no sé dónde sale o que tengo que hacer o si me hace falta algo.

esto es lo único que he hecho y quería probar si funcionaba pero no y me sale esa ventana al correr el jsp.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello friends

</body>
</html>
```

[image: E]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje parece indicar que tienes otra instancia de Tomcat ya en ejecución.

Puedes confirmarlo visitando:

- http://localhost:8080
- http://localhost:8005
- http://localhost:8009

  en tu navegador web.

Si obtienes la página principal predeterminada de Tomcat o una página de error 404 específica de Tomcat, ambos casos probarían de que en efecto hay ya en ejecución una instancia de Tomcat. Por el contrario, si no hay instancia de Tomcat corriendo, obtendrás un mensaje de error de tiempo de espera de conexión HTTP específico del navegador.

### Cerrar la instancia de Tomcat abierta

Puedes hacerlo de una de las maneras siguientes:

- Ir a la subcarpeta `/bin` de la carpeta de instalación de Tomcat y ejecutar la secuencia de comandos `shutdown.bat` (Windows) o `shutdown.sh` (Unix).
- Si no funciona, cierra Eclipse y luego abre el administrador de tareas y elimina todos los procesos java y/o javaw.
- O, si instalaste Tomcat como un servicio de Windows, abre el administrador de servicios (`Inicio> Ejecutar> services.msc`) y detén el servicio de Tomcat.

Si por algún motivo tu intención es ejecutar dos instancias de Tomcat simultáneamente, entonces tendrás que configurar la segunda instancia para escuchar en diferentes puertos. Para ello consulta la [documentación de Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/) para obtener más detalles.